# null pointer exception prob in my coding

Tags: java, exception, null, nullpointerexception

I am always getting nullPointerException on line validateCarPlate(nStr) in the main method and on line if(y.matches(rex)). How should i edit to remove the nullPointerException?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.Exception;

public class Q2{
public static void main(String[]args){
boolean loop = true;
while(loop){
   String nStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter car plate number: ");
   try{
       validateCarPlate(nStr);
}
catch(InvalidCarPlateException e){
}
}
}
public static void validateCarPlate(String y)throws InvalidCarPlateException{
String rex = "[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,4}";
if(y.matches(rex)){
    computeCheckDigit(y);
}else{
    throw new InvalidCarPlateException();
}
}

public static void computeCheckDigit(String x){
char [] arr = new char[x.length()];
for(int i=0; i<x.length();i++){
    arr[i] = x.charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: where is computeCheckDigit(y); ?

Comment: Did you check if y is null or not ?

Comment: At which line it give error

Comment: Please paste `computeCheckDigit()` method and exception.

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. i manage to get it work now. no more exception. =)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like

```
String nStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter car plate number: ");
```

this returns null

change the code like this

```
public static void main(String[]args){
  boolean loop = true;
  while(loop){
   String nStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter car plate number: ");
   if(nStr != null)
   {
     try{
       validateCarPlate(nStr);
        }
     catch(InvalidCarPlateException e){
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Since, [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29) for `JOptionPane#showInputDialog()` says ***Shows a question-message dialog requesting input from the user*** I think you forgot to give a input.

Answer (score 1):

change you method like that

```
public static void validateCarPlate(String y)throws InvalidCarPlateException{
String rex = "[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,4}";
if(y == null){
     // put some message to handle that exception such as
     // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Some Message");
}else if(y.matches(rex))
    computeCheckDigit(y);
}else{
    throw new InvalidCarPlateException();
}
}
```

Also put the code of **computeCheckDigit(y);** method.

Answer (score 1):

If you click the `Cancel` button, `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` will return a `null`. You can check the return value before passing `nStr` to `validateCarPlate`. If a `null` returned, just drop this `nStr` and continue the loop (or break it according to your requirement).